# I bought a dog. What is it good for?

Tags: fallout-4

So, while I was investigating the Museum of Witchcraft, I bumped into a traveling dog-seller who reluctantly sold me a dog.  I set up a second dog house in my backyard, watched as my adorable Dogmeat moved into it after I dismissed him in favor of Preston (1. Preston will give me a perk if I'm nice long enough, 2. Preston can wear Power Armor), and there they are, side-by-side in their little houses being dogs.

But it seems I can't get my new dog to come with me.  I can't equip it, or communicate with it.  (I'm super sad I can't equip it, Dogmeat wearing a bandana is ADORABLE and I wanted to give my bigger, meaner looking junkyard dog a Skull Bandana.)  I can't even name it - it's just Junkyard Dog.

Does the Junkyard Dog - or any other purchasable or recruitable dog besides Dogmeat - have a purpose, or do they just look good occupying my doghouses?

Comment: Perhaps they help defend the settlement?

Comment: I expect it's good for the same thing Dogmeat is good for - getting in the way.

Comment: Perhaps ask over on [Pets.SE](http://pets.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The Junkyard dog counts as 5 points of defense towards whichever settlement you send him to.
Also they create happiness in your settlements.

Comment: Additionally, he contributes to settler happiness.

Comment: As well as net fecal matter

Comment: Does he take up a population slot?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry if this is a bit late but just thought I'd share my experience.

The Junkyard dog does wear bandanas - you just can't choose or "equip" them. His bandana changes regularly so give it time and you will see him wear the skull one!

As others stated, he adds +5 to defense and if your settlement is attacked he will be the first to step into battle! I have seen some say he is invincible but he died very convincingly when I shot him...long story but he became hostile when I tried to clothe him via "pickpocket". All my settlers became hostile even though he is "my dog" so I think he does count as a settler and takes up a slot.

I do not believe he can ever be a companion as there is no way to "command" him.