# A girl and her father

Tags: fallout-4

oddly related:  [I bought a dog. What is it good for?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/244246/i-bought-a-dog-what-is-it-good-for)

I randomly bumped into a pair of survivors, one of which was a little girl, while heading towards the National Guard base.  They were polite to me, even though they didn't have much to say.  No amount of talking to them seemed to give any interaction options, though.  Hanging around nearby let me listen in to a lot of dialogue;  in particular, I noticed the girl asking if they could get a dog, "to scare the raiders away and keep me warm at night".  I was sitting there thinking I have a spare dog I'd happily give the little girl, or else I could invite them to my well-defended, resource-laden settlements...  but I simply could not figure out a way to. I never got any dialogue options at all while trying to talk to them.

So, is there a way to interact with these two?  And especially to either bring them home or give them my Junkyard Dog to protect that little girl?  I don't know if they're a random encounter or if they're in a set location, but I plan to go back looking for them again.

Comment: Did they have names? Or just "Settler".

Comment: i seem to recall them being named, but I don't recall their names.  Particularly, I remember my character "learning" the girl's name and saying it when I activate her, the same he does for Nat at Diamond City.  Looks like the Sole Survivor isn't only focused on his own kid - he seems to go out of his way to call all the children in the wastes by name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember the encounter your talking about.
As far as I know, they are simply flavor npc's, with no interactions beside idle dialogue and being murdered brutally. They can show up in multiple locations, and I have had them do so.

Answer (score -2):

You will most likely not be able to give them a dog. These are most likely random npc's to make the game more realistic. If you could give them the dog, you would be placed with dialogue. But you weren't.